# Set request character encoding of JSF input submitted values to UTF-8 in GlassFish

Tags: jsf, utf-8, character-encoding, glassfish, http-request-parameters

I have a problem with the values inserted in all my `<h:inputText>` fields. Some characters are not encoded in the right way. E.g. if I put `ciò` in the input field I get `ciÃ²`.

How can I allow a user to insert text with those characters and save them correctly? The problem in not in the DB encoding since I already have the wrong value before inserting it in the DB.

I'm using JSF 2 with Facelets and GlassFish as application server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to tell Glassfish to use UTF-8 to decode paramters instead of (default) ISO 8859-1. Add the following entry to the `<glassfish-web-app>` of your `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` file:

```
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: I have the same problem on jboss 7, any idea how to set the encoding on jboss?

Comment: @dov.amir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628354/set-request-character-encoding-of-jsf-input-submitted-values-to-utf-8