# Character issue for external directive template

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, tomcat, jsf-2

I've used angularjs for my php projects with no issues at all before. Now trying to learn `JSF`, so running tomcat and using eclipse, both for the first time. Got a simple html file to be a template for an angularjs directive with some Turkish characters like `ğ Ğ İ ı ç Ç`. When i open that file alone in a browser, i can see the characters just fine. But in the main page after directive to be loaded i saw them as `���` all. Also in the directive, i get some `json` data from another page with `$http.get` which causes no character issues at all. When i look at file props for that template file in eclipse it says `ISO 10646/Unicode(UTF-8)` for encoding. I couldnt decide where i share some code or not because i honestly dont know what to put here so what do you think i should do?

Comment: try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17643309/3728901

Comment: And can you please explain why you think this might be jsf related (you tagged it that way)

Comment: @DoNhuVy mate i'm super novice in this. I dont have any java underlying so where do i put that code?

Comment: @Kukeltje i dont know mate u tell me. I used to solve that kinda issues with header() function in php so maybe there's some kinda function in jsf too?

Comment: Hi, I'm not your mate... ;-) and kinda don't know what jsf kinda could solve for you since I kinda have no clue what you actually do. See [ask]

Comment: @BatuZet  There are many reasons for the character encoding error. You maybe post some snippets of code. Try to see HTML source in your browser. Try `<html lang="tr">` for Turkish.