# Languages other than English not displayed properly in internationalization jsf

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jsf, jsf-2.2

I am using internationalization in my jsf web application in Eclipse. I am using resource-bundle and reading from Lang.properties file using `<f:loadBundle>` tag. But when I start the server, for the first time, only the English language is displayed properly and letters of other languages are displayed as question marks. Once I refresh the page, everything is displayed properly.

I know that question marks are displayed in internationalization when jsf doesn't find the letters to display.

But I have put the key-value pairs in Lang.properties from where it should be able to read without any problem.

What should I do to make it read the Unicode letters for the first time also ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that your bundle files are saved in utf-8 encoding.
2. Your pages should have a meta `http-equiv` on top, as in :

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   ```
3. Then take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628354/set-request-character-encoding-of-jsf-input-submitted-values-to-utf-8) and its answer. I always found the web filter solution to be 100% sure thing.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? None of this all solves the problem described by the OP.

Comment: @BalusC, My jsp pages had charset and pageEncoding as ISO-8859-1. When I changed it to utf-8, it worked fine.

Comment: @chrisl08, but why was the problem happening only for the very first time when I start the server ? Once I refresh the page, everything is displayed properly.

Comment: That wasn't covered by the answer.